# How to compare two directories and find the files which were present in selected one

Tags: excel, vba, directory

I have 2 directroies
File_updated = C\Users\Desktop\Latest
File_Last = C\Users\Desktop\Last

i need to compare two directories [ updated & last ] and find out the which all are new files added in updated folder.

Example:

In updated directory - we have 325 files with new file Vlik_3.2 and 14 other files with other verisons.

Our output list should be contain 15 files name which were newly added in updated folder.

I am trying these using VBA

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show us your VBA code.

Comment: Read the content of first folder into a Dictionary (use `Dir` or a FileSystemObject). Then read the content of the second folder and check the existance in the Dictionary. If present, remove it from Dictionary. If not, you found a new file. At the end, check the Dictionary: Every entry that is still there is missing in the second folder.